# download.file timeout MODIS data

Tags: r

I am downloading MODIS data using download.file, but i always met the timeout problem. it seems it works fine for small sized file, but always appear problem for large sized files (e.g., 8M).for example:`download.file("http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLA/MYD11A2.005/2010.09.06/MYD11A2.A2010249.h10v04.005.2010264064150.hdf",myfiel.hdf,mode = "wb")`
I searched online, changed timeout as options(timeout = 240000), set setInternet2(use = TRUE)

but the problem is still not resolved. I directly copy the link to IE, it can be downloaded but take a while to start.

Do somebody has suggestion? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'm get the same error to download MOD35 and MOD03, so I found to parts of the same solution:

```
install.packages(curl)
library(curl)
# first set the internet options
setInternet2(use=FALSE)
# second use the package "curl" and the function "curl_download"
fnameMOD03 = "ftp://ladsftp.nascom.nasa.gov/allData/6/MOD03/2000/161/MOD03.A2000161.0815.006.2012253130630.hdf"

destnameMOD03 = "c:/Users/MOD03/MOD03.A2000161.0815.006.2012253130630.hdf"
curl_download(url=fnameMOD03, destfile=destnameMOD03,quiet = T, handle = new_handle())
```

Best